# Weirdness in C++03 seekoff() and seekpos() specification

Tags: c++

I am creating my own `streambuf` subclass and using the C++03 spec (ISO/IEC 14882:2003) as a reference.

In section 27.5.2.4.2 [lib.streambuf.virt.buffer], the specifications for both `basic_streambuf::seekoff()` and `basic_streambuf::seekpos()` say:

> **Default behavior:** Returns pos_type(off_type(-1)).

Now, I thought `off_type` was supposed to be a signed integral type and `pos_type` was supposed to be an unsigned integral type, so it seems to me this expression has to be equivalent to just `pos_type(-1)`.

But supposing I am mistaken, and these types might be some other combination of signed and unsigned...  Then I still cannot figure out any possible use for this double cast.

For example, if both are signed, then again the expression is equivalent to `pos_type(-1)`.

If `pos_type` were signed and `off_type` were unsigned -- which makes no sense, but bear with me -- then at best this double cast would shove some huge value into `pos_type` and at worst it would invoke implementation-defined behavior by assigning a too-large value to the signed `pos_type` integer.

Does anyone know the standard's rationale for specifying `pos_type(off_type(-1))` here instead of just `pos_type(-1)`?  If not, can you even imagine a plausible rationale?

Comment: The following paragraph is in section [fpos.operations]: Stream operations that return a value of type traits::pos_type return P(O(-1)) as an invalid value to
signal an error. If this value is used as an argument to any istream, ostream, or streambuf member that
accepts a value of type traits::pos_type then the behavior of that function is undefined. --- Maybe you can make some sense of the rest of the section, that's the only part I understood.

Comment: @Patrick: Yes, that section is indeed the key.  (See the accepted answer and my comment there.)  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that `pos_type` by default boils down to a `std::streampos`, which is typically defined like this:

`typedef fpos<mbstate_t> streampos;`

`std::fpos` is usually an offset combined with a multi-byte state object.

Additionally, `off_type` by default will boil down to a `std::streamoff` which is also a signed integral type (`long` or something like that)

So I **think** the mentality here is that you can initialize a offset type with the sentinal `-1` value, then that can be used to initialize a position object which is a more complex object. Because, `fpos`'s constructor takes `streamoff` type, not a `long`, **if** `streamoff` could be a more complex type than a `long` or similar, it would make the cautious-ness necessary.

Imagine an implementation where `streamoff` was defined like this:

```
struct streamoff {
    explicit streamoff(long offset);
    // rest of the stuff here...
};
```

Then just `pos_type(-1)` wouldn't work because there would be no implicit conversion.

So I think it's just being cautious.

Comment: Thanks for that; I was unaware that `streampos` can be a structure.  However, if `off_type` is a signed integral type, then initializing it to -1 does not give the "maximum value possible".  (Indeed, if `off_type` is a signed integral type, I do not see how `off_type(-1)` and just `-1` could be different in practice, even if `streampos` is a structure.)

Comment: Ah, I see.  These types need not be integers at all; they are only required to obey the requirements laid out in Table 88 (section 27.4.3.2, [lib.fpos.operations]).  So they could both be structures.  That answers my question; thanks!